# Variadic template variable parameter pack expansion in recursive variable definition has incorrect size

Tags: templates, variables, variadic-templates, fold

While working on a low-level network device driver, I needed to do numerous bit-field operations involving masking, shifting, etc. in order to set/clr control bits in various control registers.  As there are many registers and many fields to initialize, the canonical way of managing bit fields via C++ &, |, and << operators leads to code that is very error prone and difficult to read and maintain.

I came up with the idea to create a constexpr global constant (MASK_1) that accepts a list of bit-field sizes and offsets and generates a 64-bit constant mask for the defined fields.  For example :

`auto static constexpr mask = MASK_1 <0 , 4 , 60 , 4> ; // mask = 0xF00000000000000F`

While attempting to implement this idea, I get a compile-time error that seems like a bug in the compiler.

My first attempt at defining the MASK_1 variable was to use a variadic template variable of the following :

```
template <unsigned LSB , unsigned NB , unsigned ... LSB_NB_LIST> requires (1U <= NB && NB <= 64U) && (LSB + NB <= 64U) && (sizeof ... (LSB_NB_LIST) % 2U == 0U)

constexpr uint64_t MASK_1 = (((uint64_t (-1) >> 64 - NB) << LSB) | ... | MASK_1 <LSB_NB_LIST>) ;
```

This form uses the parameter pack in a fold expression with a left-side initialization and, to my knowledge, is valid in C++20.

Trying to compile this yields an error message that the recursive reference parameter pack is too short.  I have confirmed my test cases to have exactly 2, 4, or 6 arguments leading to 0 , 2 , or 4 parameter pack arguments, so there is no mismatch in the number of expected arguments.

I tried rewriting the MASK_1 constant using a lambda according to the following and it works fine :

```
template <unsigned LSB , unsigned NB , unsigned ... LSB_NB_LIST> requires (1U <= NB && NB <= 64U) && (LSB + NB <= 64U) && (sizeof ... (LSB_NB_LIST) % 2U == 0U)

constexpr uint64_t MASK_1 = [] (void) noexcept -> uint64_t
{
  auto const mask_1 = (uint64_t (-1) >> 64 - NB) << LSB ;

  if constexpr  (sizeof ... (LSB_NB_LIST) == 0)
    {
      return mask_1 ;
    }
  else
    {
      return mask_1 | MASK_1 <LSB_NB_LIST ...> ;
    }
} () ;
```

I also tried to use a fold expression in the second attempt as below, but it too generates an error :

```
template <unsigned LSB , unsigned NB , unsigned ... LSB_NB_LIST> requires (1U <= NB && NB <= 64U) && (LSB + NB <= 64U) && (sizeof ... (LSB_NB_LIST) % 2U == 0U)

constexpr uint64_t MASK_1 = [] (void) noexcept -> uint64_t
{
  auto const mask_1 = (uint64_t (-1) >> 64 - NB) << LSB ;

  if constexpr  (sizeof ... (LSB_NB_LIST) == 0)
    {
      return mask_1 ;
    }
  else
    {
      return (mask_1 | ... | MASK_1 <LSB_NB_LIST>) ;
    }
} () ;
```

At this point, it appears that there is a bug in my compiler (GCC 11.2.0).

Can anyone confirm if this is a compiler bug or if I am somehow incorrectly doing the fold expression syntax in the first and third attempts?

EDIT:

Here is the minimal test code :

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdint>

template <unsigned LSB , unsigned NB , unsigned ... LSB_NB_LIST> requires (1U <= NB && NB <= 64U) && (LSB + NB <= 64U) && (sizeof ... (LSB_NB_LIST) % 2U == 0U)

constexpr uint64_t MASK_1 = (((uint64_t (-1) >> 64 - NB) << LSB) | ... | MASK_1 <LSB_NB_LIST>) ;

int main (int argc , char * args [])
{
  printf ("%016llX\n" , MASK_1 <0 , 4>) ;          // Works

  printf ("%016llX\n" , MASK_1 <0 , 4 , 60 , 4>) ; // Error
}
```

Here is the compiler call :

```
g++ --std=c++20 -I. -o m.exe main.cpp
```

Here is the compiler error message :

```
main.cpp: In instantiation of 'constexpr const uint64_t MASK_1<0, 4, 60, 4>':
main.cpp:12:25:   required from here
main.cpp:6:74: error: wrong number of template arguments (1, should be at least 2)
    6 | constexpr uint64_t MASK_1 = (((uint64_t (-1) >> 64 - NB) << LSB) | ... | MASK_1 <LSB_NB_LIST>) ;
      |                                                                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
main.cpp:6:20: note: provided for 'template<unsigned int LSB, unsigned int NB, unsigned int ...LSB_NB_LIST>  requires 1 <= NB && NB <= 64 && LSB + NB <= 64 && sizeof ... ((LSB_NB_LIST ...)) % 2 == 0 constexpr const uint64_t MASK_1<LSB, NB, LSB_NB_LIST ...>'
    6 | constexpr uint64_t MASK_1 = (((uint64_t (-1) >> 64 - NB) << LSB) | ... | MASK_1 <LSB_NB_LIST>) ;
      |                    ^~~~~~
```

EDIT-2 : Lambda method that works

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdint>

template <unsigned LSB , unsigned NB , unsigned ... LSB_NB_LIST> requires (1U <= NB && NB <= 64U) && (LSB + NB <= 64U) && (sizeof ... (LSB_NB_LIST) % 2U == 0U)

#if 0

constexpr uint64_t MASK_1 = (((uint64_t (-1) >> 64 - NB) << LSB) | ... | MASK_1 <LSB_NB_LIST>) ;

#else

constexpr uint64_t MASK_1 = [] (void) noexcept -> uint64_t
{
  auto const mask_1 = (uint64_t (-1) >> 64 - NB) << LSB ;

  if constexpr  (sizeof ... (LSB_NB_LIST) == 0)
    {
      return mask_1 ;
    }
  else
    {
      return mask_1 | MASK_1 <LSB_NB_LIST ...> ;
    }
} () ;

#endif

int main (int argc , char * args [])
{
  printf ("%016llX\n" , MASK_1 <0 , 4>) ;          // Works

  printf ("%016llX\n" , MASK_1 <0 , 4 , 60 , 4>) ; // Works
}
```

Comment: Compiles just fine for me. If you have a compiler error, show it verbatim, together with the complete source that leads to it.

Comment: Just edited the original question to add the code, compiler call, and error messages.

Comment: Ah that is what doesn't compile. Seems fair to me. How do you imagine the compiler expanding this fold expression? It doesn't know you want the template parameters to come in pairs. There is no way to build a fold expression like that.

Comment: You could build a template that accepts pairs of values luke `MASK<{0,4},{60,4}>` instead, and use a fold expression there.

Comment: Actually, using a lambda and embedding the fold expression there works fine.  also, what you suggest only changes the type and not the number of arguments, so is subject to the same issue. It appears that one method of using a fold expression is compiled correctly and the other is not.  I have also confirmed that the constraints are indeed checking for an even number of arguments and fail when their is not.  Please see the second edit where I added the code that works.

Comment: You have an old school recursive definition, not a fold expression. There is no reason why a recursive definition should not work. What I suggested changes the number of parameters from an even number of integers to any number of pairs, but whatever.

Comment: I understand the recursion, but I don't understand why going from an even pair of integers to any number of pairs should make a difference.  From the cppreference.com site,  a valid syntax for a fold expression is ( init op ... op pack ) which I think I am doing.  I can't see why the parameter pack is not being expanded correctly.

Comment: I just tried a quick test  : constexpr uint64_t MASK_1 = sizeof ... (LSB_NB_LIST) ;  This returns a value that correctly matches the number of template arguments passed.  So I can't see why the fold expression (first case) still thinks there is only one argument.

Comment: Ok, I finally understand your comment and why the 'tuple' option would work.  The fold expression is indeed expanding correctly, one argument at a time, but MASK_1 requires two.  Instead of MARK_1 <arg , arg> | ... it is doing MARK_1<arg> | MARC_1 <arg> and that is why the error message shows the errror.  Thanks!

Comment: Correcting spelling error MASK_1 instead of MARK_1...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here, as I have come to understand, is a mismatch between what I **think** should be happening vs what is **actually** happening.

The original expression :

```
constexpr uint64_t MASK_1 = (((uint64_t (-1) >> 64 - NB) << LSB) | ... | MASK_1 <LSB_NB_LIST>) ;
```

This is actually doing the following :

```
constexpr uint64_t MASK_1 = (uint64_t (-1) >> 64 - NB) << LSB | MASK_1 <LSB_1> | MASK_1 <NB_1> | MASK_1 <LSB_2> | MASK_1 <NB_2> | ... ;
```

instead of what I **thought** it was supposed to do :

```
constexpr uint64_t MASK_1 = ((uint64_t (-1) >> 64 - NB) << LSB | MASK_1 <LSB_1 , NB_1> | MASK_1 <LSB_2 , NB_2> | ... ;
```

Which is why the compiler emits the correct error message stating the wrong number of arguments for MASK_1 in the binary fold expression.

For the lambda method, the recursive call to MASK_1 actually passes the whole parameter pack, so is correct.